# Date in ajax post data to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to post a DateTime from javascript to my MVC controller. The datetime string is in format yy-mm-dd hh:mm. This is my javascript code:

```
 var dataObject = {
         dateData: New Date('16-01-01 15:30')
        }

        console.log(dataObject);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/DateTest")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataObject,
            },
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my MVC controller:

```
  public ActionResult DateTest(DateObject data)
        {
            return Json("ok", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

However in my DateObject i get "{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}".

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what framework is the MVC in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

For starters you are using invalid javascript and getting an error on this line:

```
dateData: New Date('16-01-01 15:30')
```

Remember that javascript is a case-sensitive language, so I guess you probably wanted to use the Date constructor:

```
dateData: new Date('16-01-01 15:30')
```

Also using ISO8601 is the recommended format that you should pass to the constructor:

```
dateData: new Date('2016-01-01T15:30')
```

You might also convert it to a string before sending:

```
dateData: new Date('2016-01-01T15:30').toISOString()
```

Comment: Same problem when using dateData: new Date('01-01-2016T15:30'), could it be that dateData in my c# object is of type DateTime?

Comment: new Date('01-01-2016T15:30') in the console gives Invalid Date

Comment: Try using `toISOString()` before sending. Also use the `2016-01-01T15:30` format. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: If I wanted to pass multiple date values, can I do it with 
data: "{'date1': 'dataObject1', 'date2':'dataObject2'}",?

Answer (score 1):

You must use correct date format in Date object:

```
var dataObject = {
   dateData: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")
}

console.log(dataObject);

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/DateTest")',
   dataType: "json",
   data: dataObject,
   success: function (response) {
    // whatever you need to do in case of success
   }
});
```

Best solution for Javascript Date object:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to call *JSON.stringify(dateData)* for you *data* property in the ajax request. If your date is not serialiazed, the model binder will not be able to deseiralize it correctly. In a general manner, use *JSON.stringify* each time you pass a javascript object with a *dataType: json*.
You had some mistakes in you *$.ajax()* call also.
Here's a corrected version:

```
var dataObject = {
    dateData: new Date('16-01-01 15:30')
}

console.log(dataObject);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Content("~/Service/DateTest")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataObject,
    success: function (response) {
        // whatever you need to do in case of success
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the below code you can properly format your datetime from ajax success section so it is displayed properly in your view.

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
      var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
      var results = pattern.exec(value);
      var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
      return dt.getFullYear() + "/" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate();
}
```